# How to retreive password stored in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, password

I would like to retrieve an important password which I forgot, but which Firefox has remembered and uses to log in. Where is this password stored and is it (or can it be made) readable?

Comment: You can find it at here - http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/find-a-forgotten-password-saved-in-firefox/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Edit` --> `Preferences` --> `Security Tab` and select `Saved Passwords`

[image]

Then select `Show Passwords`

[image]

Comment: Glad to help ;-)